# Giving error req.data undefined using passport in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var user = require('../modal/admin');

exports.passport = (passport) => {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
},
    (username, password, done, req) => {
        console.log(req)
        user.findOne(({ username: username }),  async (err, user) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
        const cpassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!cpassword) { return done(null, false); }
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                id:user.id,
                username:user.username
            },
            "shubham"            
        );
        adminRecords = {
            token:token
        }
        req.data = adminRecords  ====>>>> Error here
        console.log(adminRecords)
        return done(null, user, adminRecords);
        });
    }
 ))
};
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
 done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
 user.find(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user)       
 });
});
```

route.js

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'));
```

It's giving error req.data is not defined. I am using passport local strategy and want to return jwt token in req.data. It is not taking req parameter correctly.

Comment: Is that the exact and complete code and error message that you get? Judging from the code, that seems unlikely.

Comment: updated complete code and it is giving this error as it is not taking req parameter correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback function have only 3 params

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
},
    (username, password, done, req) => { // callback function have only 3 params 
// Additional codes
```

Solution try to use middleware when you authenticate

```
app.use(request, response, next) => { passport.authenticate('local', (err, token, info) => {
 if (token) {
 request.login(token, () => { // Do your logic });
 } else { } 
})(request, response, next); });
```

Comment: If callback have only 3 params then how can i use req as i want it for jwt token. If i use it after this it returns error passport.use is not function

Comment: try to use middleware ```app.use(request, response, next) => {
    passport.authenticate(''passportjsname', (err, token, info) => {
        if (token) {
            request.login(token, () => {
                // Do your logic
            });
        } else {    
        }
    })(request, response, next);
});``` remove```req.data=adminRecords```

Comment: I am getting token in info now but api does not get any response

Comment: router.post('/log', (req, res, next) => { passport.authenticate('local', (err, token, info) => {
    if (info) {
        console.log(info)
    req.data = info;
    } else { } 
   })(req, res, next); });

Comment: once you set data in request then all next middleware
```router.post('/log', (req, res, next) => { 
       passport.authenticate('local', (err, token, info) => { if (info) { 
         console.log(info) 
         req.data = info;
         next(); // added newly
      } else { } })(req, res, next); });```

Comment: Yes I have to use next parameter thanx bro will try and tell you silly mistake